# convert sql subquery to linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm trying to convert a simple subquery to LINQ (c#):

```
select * from tblFundtoFiscalYear ftfy
where ftfy.FiscalYear = 2015 
    and ftfy.FundID =(
        SELECT FundID
        FROM tblAccountDirectParent]
        where ParentAccountID = 19 )
```

Something along the lines of:

```
var queryFTFY =
    from ftfy in FRATContext.tblFundtoFiscalYear
    where ftfy.FiscalYear == 2015 
        && ftfy.FundID =
            (from adp in FRATContext.tblAccountDirectParent
             where adp.ParentAccountID == 19
             select adp.FundID)
    select new
    {
        ftfy.FundtoFiscalYearID
    };
```

Assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: so what is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SQL relies on the assumption that the subquery returns just one result. You can make this explicit in your LINQ:

```
var queryFTFY =
    from ftfy in FRATContext.tblFundtoFiscalYear
    where ftfy.FiscalYear == 2015 && ftfy.FundID ==
    (
        from adp in FRATContext.tblAccountDirectParent
        where adp.ParentAccountID == 19
        select adp.FundID
    ).Single()
    select ftfy;
```

Alternatively, you could reformulate the query (in both cases) as a join:

```
var queryFTFY =
    from ftfy in FRATContext.tblFundtoFiscalYear
    join adp in FRATContext.tblAccountDirectParent
    on ftfy.FundID equals adp.FundID
    where ftfy.FiscalYear == 2015 
       && adp.ParentAccountID == 19
    select ftfy;
```

Comment: +1 - `JOIN`s are the most effective method to perform this task. Though, if the OP's database does not enforce referential integrity the data may not properly resolve.

Comment: Thank you Douglas.  Both those suggestions worked!  I am only retrieving a single value.  Could you also tell me the proper way to get that value.  I do it with:   foreach (var f in queryFTFY)
                    {
                        fundToFiscalYearL3 =  f.FundtoFiscalYearID;         
                    }

Comment: @John: You can call `Single` on the query: `int fundToFiscalYearL3 = queryFTFY.Single().FundtoFiscalYearID`. If there are cases where you might get no rows, use `SingleOrDefault()` instead (and check for null).

Comment: I'm having an issue using that returned value in a where clause on another query right after that one.  I have the field defined as  public int fundToFiscalYearIDL3 { get; set; } but when I use it in the next query I get a fatal error fatal error about the stack being corrupted
"user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke".  If I hardcode the value the query runs fine.  It must haves something to do about the variable or the way/timing I'm using it.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @John: That kind of error shouldn't occur from your code above. I'd suggest posting a new question with more context (such as whether you're using a custom data provider).